# CSS: transform scale by pixel rather than proportion

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of cards on a page. They scale up on hover. The cards are of **variable size**, and some cards will scale up too much since the **scale is a proportion**. I would like to scale up less for a bigger card, and more for a smaller card. E.g, **scaling up every card by, say, 10px.**

Note that solutions changing the paddings etc aren't great because they don't cause the rest of the content to scale (e.g. font sizes etc).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.card {
  background: red;
  margin: 3rem;
  
}

.card:hover {
   transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="card">
Hello </div>

<div class="card">
Hello more text text text this is a lot of text we go on forever it never stops </div></div>
```

Note, in the snippet, how the right card appears to scale up much much more than the smaller one. Is there any **CSS-only solution** to this problem?

Comment: Maybe you can set the `font-size` to increase on hover? Maybe you have to add other properties too, but in the end you may end up with something looking similar to `scale`. This way you can use absolute values.

Answer (score 0):

you can use some imitation of card magnification

```
.card:hover{box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px red} 
.card:hover{outline: 10px solid red}
```